# PowerShell - Create objects with different names

Tags: powershell

How it is possible to create a object and numbering it?

I want to run a loop and create objects with different names.

```
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
$n = 30

for($i = 0 ; $i -le $n; $i++)
{
($ie +$i) = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
($ie +$i).visible = $true
($ie +$i).Navigate($url)
}
```

So that the results are the objects:

$ie1
$ie2
$ie3
etc.

Comment: As @JPBlanc said, you can use `New-Variable`, but why don't you create an array of objects? You could then access the individual objects with `$ie[0]`, `$ie[1]`, etc. This makes it easier to iterate through all of the objects (eg. to close all instances of Internet explorer: `$ie| foreach { $_.Quit() }`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `New-Variable` CmdLet to create a var in wich you compose the name dynamicaly.

```
PS C:\Temp> $a = "AV"
PS C:\Temp> $newV = New-Variable -Name ($a+"123") -Value (New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application)
PS C:\Temp> Get-Variable av123

Name                           Value
----                           -----
AV123                          System.__ComObject
```